# System.Web.UI.ViewStateException : Invalid viewstate

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, antiforgerytoken

I'm getting weird errors ever since my hosting company decided to upgrade (and restart) my web server.

Here are the facts, broken down

- MVC 2 Application
- Windows 2008 Server
- Machine Key defined in the webconfig (and in machine config- same exact key)
- Machine key was defined in the web.config for the site before the maintenance
- Site uses its own app pool running as Network Service
- I am not using viewstate, but I am using the anti forgery token

Despite doing everything stated, I am still getting numerous errors like this:

> System.Web.UI.ViewStateException : Invalid viewstate. Client IP: [OMITTED] Port: 56668 Referer: https://someserver.com Path: /Framed/CreditCard/ User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; Trident/4.0; GTB7.1; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618) ViewState: [OMITTED]

I was able to recreate the error once, but after that it stopped.  I thought I had fixed it, but my clients still get the error.

EDIT:
I thought originally this had been because of the worker process recycling.  This is not the case, as I have made pushes to the web server with changes that have cause the WP to recycle.  I do however believe it was something in the updates they may have done last night.  Waiting to hear back on a report of what they did.

Comment: Is your [anti forgery token within a form?](http://forums.asp.net/t/1479165.aspx/1?Invalid+viewstate+exception+when+using+AntiForgeryToken)

Comment: Yes, it is.  No code changed between it working just fine and the maintenance that my hosting company did last night.

Comment: "I was able to recreate the error once [...] but I still get the error"; which is it? :)

Comment: I edited the text.  I personally received the error once.  My system e-mails me error reports whenever a client experiences an error.  I have been getting e-mails about this error.

Comment: did you get any solution.
i am getting same error...
i have asp.net 2.0 web farm based website, its running from couple of month and i am getting same error "System.Web.UI.ViewStateException : Invalid viewstate " all sudden on one page on button click, but not on other page with button click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We moved to a new hosting environment, and I still periodically see this error.  I ended up removing the Antiforgery token from most of my site, and in all new development I do not make use of it.  For some reason it just fails to operate as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I read an article before, may be it's the same problem you have

http://keylimetie.com/blog/2006/9/24/viewstate/

Comment: I don't think my users are using anything like that.  This site is a payment gateway.  Thanks for the suggestion though.